# hubspot onFormReady populate form field

Tags: jquery, forms, hubspot

I have a hubspot form embedded on a page and i'm trying to pre-populate a field with jQuery. I want to use the text that is between an H2 tag with the class "djc_title" that is elsewhere in the page and with it populate an input field with the ID of "productname" in the embedded form.  Here is my code. I'm sure it's all wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
hbspt.forms.create({ 
    portalId: '',
    formId: '',
    onFormReady: function($form) {
        $(“#productname”).val($("h2.djc_title").text());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Below code work for me. It may help someone.

```
 hbspt.forms.create({
    portalId: "*******",
    formId: "formid********",
        onFormReady: function($form){
        $form.find('input[name="firstname"]').val('Brian').change();
}
})
```

You need to use `onFormReady` callback which will provide `$form` params. We can use it to populate the value as `$form` has the `id` of all the input fields.

```
  $form.find('input[name="email"]').val('example@gmail.com').change();
```

Comment: It works properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it may be helpful to update the `onFormReady` function to correspond to the Hubspot fields as described on the API docs.

Examples:

```
$('input[value="checkbox_1"]').prop('checked', true).change();
$('input[name="firstname"]').val('Brian').change();
```

There are some examples on this page:

http://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/advanced_form_options